# repetition-operator operand invalid in grep command

Tags: grep

I was trying to search for the string "BCR" in any file under Dropbox folder this manner :

```
grep -E -rnw "*BCR*" ~/Dropbox
```

but I got the following error :

> grep: repetition-operator operand invalid

Is there a kind of redundancy in what the command I wrote ? I'm using bash-3.2 under Mac OSX El Capitan.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that your regex starts with `*` which is a repetition operator but nothing precedes it hence the error.

Comment: Well, it's actually more complicated than that... For the record, in a BRE if the 1st char is  `*` it loses its special meaning and it matches a literal `*` - in a ERE it depends on the implementation e.g. `OSX grep` spits an error while `GNU grep` silently ignores it... Because you invoked `grep` with `-E` (means ERE) and because you're on OSX you get the above error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti)'s [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314228/repetition-operator-operand-invalid-in-grep-command/314229#comment552299_314228), the `*` operator in a regular expression needs an operand; in your case, `.` which stands for "any character":

```
grep -E -rnw ".*BCR.*" ~/Dropbox
```

You can get the same result without using a regular expression:

```
grep -rn BCR ~/Dropbox
```

Comment: "parenthesis are not balanced"

Comment: @Gargo you’re going to have to be more specific. There aren’t any parentheses in the expressions given in the answer.