# Grep: repetition-operator operand invalid in GNU Parallel call

Tags: shell-script, grep, osx, gnu-parallel

I am creating a function to be called in parallel using GNU's parallel package in OSX. The function is as such:

```
parallel_func() {
    (cat $1) | grep -ioE "($first$second$third+$fourth)"
}
export -f parallel_func
parallel doit ::: $Files_To_Parse
```

When I call this function I receive the error: "grep: repetition-operator operand invalid"

However, when I perform the grep statement sequentially with a for loop it works as expected:

```
for file in $Files_To_Parse; do
    (cat $file) | grep -ioE "($first$second$third+$fourth)"
done
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is and how to fix the parallel function to not throw an error?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? why the subshell in `(cat $1)`? why the chain of greps? Anyhow perhaps `grep` in your interactive shell is GNU grep (which IIRC has a special rule the treats `*` at the start of a pattern as literal) versus OSX/BSD grep when you use `parallel` - see [repetition-operator operand invalid in grep command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314228/repetition-operator-operand-invalid-in-grep-command) - try `grep "\*"`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I am searching in a large list of files for matches to regex patterns. The chain of greps is to filter out matches that contain asterisks or the word "null". The (cat $1) in the 2nd chunk of code is a copy and paste typo. And yes, the code was from the mentioned link.

Comment: `for file in /path/to/files/*; do grep -ioE "($first$second$third+$fourth) "$file"; done`.  Don't `cat file | grep pattern`; just `grep pattern file`.  If you want to parellelize it, replace the semicolon with an ampersand.

Comment: DO NOT just use & for parallelization where you want use the output. You risk mixing: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_alternatives.html#Output-mixes

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Technically you can replace the `(cat "$1") |` with `< "$1"` if you want.

```
Files_To_Parse=myfile
seq 10000000 > $Files_To_Parse
first=1
second=2
third=3
fourth=4
export first
export second
export third
export fourth

parallel_func() {
    (cat "$1") | grep -ioE "($first$second$third+$fourth)"
}
export -f parallel_func
parallel parallel_func ::: $Files_To_Parse
```